gcloud command output formatting with previous variables of the another gcloud command
I have:
var=$(gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances ig --region=europe-west1 --format="csv[no-heading](NAME)")

gcloud compute instance-groups describe ig --format="csv[no-heading](name,$var)"

Get error:
**ERROR**: (gcloud.compute.instance-groups.describe) Non-empty key name expected [default csv[no-heading](name, *HERE* '')]
Any idea to resolve this?
Thanks in advance
Regards

You can use variables in gcloud commands but this will only work when the variable's use is syntactically correct which it isn't in this case. What are you trying to do? Produce a CSV of Instance Group name paired with the Instance name? I don't have Instance Groups deployed to test, what is the obfuscated output of cloud compute instance-groups list-instances ig --region=europe-west1 --format=yaml? instancesGroup.listInstances should have this response body

Turn on shell debugging with set -x (set +x to turn off) to see what values are populating the 2nd command. ALSO, can you get a plain text version of your 2nd command to work (no variables, all plain text)?

@DazWilkin Yes, get a CSV file of Instance Group name paired with the Instance name. YAML don't work hhere to extract data because is more tedious.Ty 4 response

@shellter first command get only a name instance , second command I want get a instance_group with all instances group it, in this case 2 instances names ("instance1,instance2", without quotes). Ty 4 response

You can get all the information you need from the first command:
NAME="..." # Instance Group name
REGION="..."
PROJECT="..."

gcloud compute instance-groups list-instances ${NAME} \
--region=${REGION} \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(format(\"${NAME},{0}\",instance))"

This uses the format projection to generate a CSV formatted line combining the Instance Group name (${NAME}) with the instance (name).
Bash will replace the value of ${NAME} with its value before it invokes gcloud but the result is (I think) what you want.

Nice! thanks a lot!!

You're welcome! Glad that it helped
